# A question on Perron–Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A \in M_n$ is nonnegative(all $a_{ij}\ge0$).

Suppose $A$ has a nonnegative eigenvector(all entries$\ge0$ ) with $r ≥ 1$ positive entries and $n − r$ zero entries.

Why is there a permutation matrix $P$, such that ${P^T}AP = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   B & C  \\
   0 & D  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ is nonnegative,$B\in M_r$ , $D\in M_{n−r}$ , and $B$ has a positive eigenvector?

Comment: Didn't you ask this in another question a day or so ago?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @IgorRivin I asked because I am sure the other one was closed and had the same wording.